# I don't understand a end keyword usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting pretty confused with the keyword end. For example, in the following code, I'm tried to define a my own helper method but I got too many SyntaxErrors because I missed some ends. I added some and it's works but... I don't understand why I have to put them, which *block* they close.

I marked them with multiple questions marks.

Thanks guys!

```
 module ApplicationHelper

      def notice_color(notice)
        if notice
            type = type_notice(notice)
            div_tag_head = "<div class=\"alert alert-#{type} alert-dismissable\">"
            cross_button = "<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>"
            notice_tag = div_tag_head + cross_button + notice + "</div>"
            notice_tag.to_s.html_safe
        end # If's end.
      end   # Def's end.

    def type_notice(notice)
        downcased = notice.downcase
        if downcased.include? 'error' or downcased.include? 'invalid'
          return'danger'
        else if downcased.include? 'done' or downcased.include? 'success'
          return 'success'
        else if downcased.include? 'hey'
          return 'warning'
        else 
          return 'info'
        end # If's end.
      end #Def's end
    end # ?????? <------ First

      private :type_notice
    end # ??????? <------ Second
    end # Module's end
```

Comment: If you consistently used 2-space indentation these errors would be more obvious. You've got a mix of 4 and 2 here.

Comment: Hey man! Thanks, I was searching a way to configure SublimeText to format the code, but what I found don't work pretty well : / Anyways, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Usually you just have to use the indent/unindent block feature to line things up correctly, eyeballing it and getting things in order. It might seem like a minor issue, but block nesting is a big deal when it comes to readability and debugging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is in the `if` block.  Ruby syntax is `elsif` not `else if`:

```
if downcased.include? 'error' or downcased.include? 'invalid'
  return'danger'
elsif downcased.include? 'done' or downcased.include? 'success'
  return 'success'
elsif downcased.include? 'hey'
  return 'warning'
else 
  return 'info'
end
```

Your two `else if` lines are actually starting two new `if` statements, hence why you needed a couple of extra `end`s.

Answer (score 0):

As Graeme stated, be careful to use `elsif` instead of `else if`.

However, indentation may also have played a role in the confusion. If you're using Sublime Text, check the Preferences.sublime-settings file and make sure there's a line that says `"tab_size": 2` or `"tab_size": n` (n being any number you're comfortable with, though 2 is de facto industry standard). Be careful to add a comma after the code if it's in the middle of the hash.

To access the preferences file, in Sublime Text, press Shift + Command + p (on an Apple) and type 'user,' or find the Preferences menu option and select 'Settings - User.'